# How to edit an individual cell in a datagrid?

Tags: c#, datagrid, row, cell

What I am looking to do is be able to edit three cells in a datagrid row? Is it possible to edit only those three cells? or would the whole row have to be editable? And how would I do this? Would it be done through an event? Thanks.

Comment: datagrid as winforms or webforms?

Comment: By editable do you mean: You want to change the displayed value programmatically, or, that you want the user to be able to edit/change the value displayed in the field (like, with textboxes).

Comment: yeah i want the user to be able to change the value in the field.

Comment: So you want to allow user to edit only three cells of one row in complete dataGrid? or do you want to allow user to only edit three cells of each row?

Comment: yeah, well, i want those three cells to be editable in every row.

Comment: Gotta read some documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say your DataGrid have four column col1, col2, col3 and col4 and you only want to allow user to edit first three.

you can set the fourth column to read only.

`col4.IsReadOnly = true`. This will work

This can be done while initializing DataGrid or while defining DataGridColumn

Comment: how would I make the changes in the code so that whatever user changes in the grid, will save back to the database?

Comment: do a search on "data binding" which btw is a separate question